# Limit the size of dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift4

I have a dictionary like this:

```
static var answer = [String: String]()
```

How can I limit the number of items to a specific number?

Comment: Any what use would you get from by limiting the number of elements?

Comment: Each time a user clicks, a value will add to the dictionary. After a certain number, nothing should be added

Comment: Write a proper data model class/struct that enforces whatever logic you need.

Comment: You should handle on user click rather than limiting the number of items in dictionary.

Comment: Why do you need this limitation? A dictionary might not be the best candidate for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple way:

```
var answer = [String: String]()
let limit = 3

func addToDictionary(key: String, value: String) {
    let keys = answer.keys
    if keys.count < limit || keys.contains(key) {
        answer[key] = value
    }
}

addToDictionary(key: "uno", value: "one")
addToDictionary(key: "dos", value: "two")
addToDictionary(key: "tres", value: "three")
addToDictionary(key: "quatro", value: "four")
addToDictionary(key: "tres", value: "trois")

print(answer) //["uno": "one", "tres": "trois", "dos": "two"]
```

This won't prevent adding directly to the dictionary via `answer["cinco"] = "five"`. The proper way would be to create a struct that has the limit property. Here is an example implementation:

```
struct LimitedDictionary<T: Hashable, U> {
    private let limit: UInt
    private var dictionary = [T: U]()

    init(limit: UInt) {
        self.limit = limit
    }

    subscript(key: T) -> U? {
        get {
            return dictionary[key]
        }
        set {
            let keys = dictionary.keys
            if keys.count < limit || keys.contains(key) {
                dictionary[key] = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    func getDictionary() -> [T: U] {
        return dictionary
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var dict = LimitedDictionary<String, String>(limit: 3)

dict["uno"] = "one"
dict["dos"] = "two"
dict["tres"] = "three"
dict["quatro"] = "four"
dict["tres"] = "trois"

dict["uno"]          //"one"
dict.getDictionary() //["dos": "two", "tres": "trois", "uno": "one"]
```

Comment: This is why you should write a proper data model class. So you can enforce the required logic.

Comment: @Carpsen90 You could add subscript support using `subscript(key: String)` as shown [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html)